# Why do I get a SyntaxError for a Unicode escape in my file path?

Tags: python, windows, filenames

The folder I want to get to is called python and is on my desktop.

I get the following error when I try to get to it

```
>>> os.chdir('C:\Users\expoperialed\Desktop\Python')
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Try `s.chdir(r'C:\Users\expoperialed\Desktop\Python')`; read: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Answer (score 187):

You need to use a *raw* string, double your slashes or use forward slashes instead:

```
r'C:\Users\expoperialed\Desktop\Python'
'C:\\Users\\expoperialed\\Desktop\\Python'
'C:/Users/expoperialed/Desktop/Python'
```

In regular Python strings, the `\U` character combination signals an extended Unicode codepoint escape.

You can hit any number of other issues, for any of the other [recognised escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), such as `\a`, `\t`, or `\x`.

Note that as of Python 3.6, unrecognized escape sequences can trigger a [`DeprecationWarning`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#DeprecationWarning) (you'll have to remove the default filter for those), and in a future version of Python, such unrecognised escape sequences will cause a `SyntaxError`. No specific version has been set at this time, but Python will first use `SyntaxWarning` in the version before it'll be an error.

If you want to find issues like these in Python versions 3.6 and up, you can turn the warning into a `SyntaxError` exception by using the warnings filter `error:^invalid escape sequence .*:DeprecationWarning` (via a [command line switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W), [environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS) or [function call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings)):

```
Python 3.10.0 (default, Oct 15 2021, 22:25:32) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import warnings
>>> '\expoperialed'
'\\expoperialed'
>>> warnings.filterwarnings('default', '^invalid escape sequence .*', DeprecationWarning)
>>> '\expoperialed'
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence '\e'
'\\expoperialed'
>>> warnings.filterwarnings('error', '^invalid escape sequence .*', DeprecationWarning)
>>> '\expoperialed'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    '\expoperialed'
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence '\e'
```

Answer (score 6):

This usually happens in Python 3. One of the common reasons would be that while specifying your file path you need "\\" instead of "\". As in:

```
filePath = "C:\\User\\Desktop\\myFile"
```

For Python 2, just using "\" would work.

Comment: This happens in Python 2 just as much, but `\Uxxxxxxxx` only works in Unicode strings, so `u'....'`. There are other escape sequences that would trigger the same issue in Python 2 bytestrings, such as `\Users\xander`, where the `\x` is the start of a hex escape sequence.

Answer (score 5):

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\Pooja\\Desktop\\trolldata.csv')
```

Use '\\' for python program in Python version 3 and above..
Error will be resolved..

Comment: why triple `\\`? Editing typo? Ok now I see post history and someone fixed formatting not carefully enough, so I've fixed that. Please familiarize yourself it with [SO features](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: This happens in Python 2 just as much, but `\Uxxxxxxxx` only works in Unicode strings, so `u'....'`. There are other escape sequences that would trigger the same issue in Python 2 bytestrings, such as `\Users\xander`, where the `\x` is the start of a hex escape sequence. This answer otherwise just repeats what I stated in 2013.

Comment: I got this error when I included a path starting with 'C:\Users\' _in a comment_ between triple quotes, using '\\' solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

All the three syntax work very well.

Another way is to first write

path = r'C:\user\...................' (whatever is the path for you)

and then passing it to os.chdir(path)

Comment: Yes, `r'....'` is one of those three options I named in my 2013 answer.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error.
Basically, I suspect that the path cannot start either with "U" or "User" after "C:\".
I changed my directory to "c:\file_name.png" by putting the file that I want to access from python right under the 'c:\' path.

In your case, if you have to access the "python" folder, perhaps reinstall the python, and change the installation path to something like "c:\python". Otherwise, just avoid the "...\User..." in your path, and put your project under C:.

Comment: Did you read my answer from 2013 yet? Paths can start with `U` just fine. There is no need to reinstall anything.