# Python open file unicode error

Tags: python

I'm learning how to open a file in Python, but when I type the path to the file I want to open, a window pops up, saying "(unicode error) 'unicodeescape codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape". It highlights the first of my parentheses. Here's the code:

```
with open ("C:\Users\Rajrishi\Documents\MyJava\text.txt") as myfile:
    data = myfile.readlines()
print(data)
```

Comment: Please include your file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a SyntaxError for a Unicode escape in my file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084554/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-for-a-unicode-escape-in-my-file-path)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One obvious problem is that you're using a normal string, not a raw string. In

```
open ("C:\Users\Rajrishi\Documents\MyJava\text.txt") 
                                         ^^
```

the `\t` is interpreted as a tab character, not a literal backslash, followed by `t`.

Use one of the following:

```
open("C:\\Users\\Rajrishi\\Documents\\MyJava\\text.txt") # meh
open(r"C:\Users\Rajrishi\Documents\MyJava\text.txt")     # better
open("C:/Users/Rajrishi/Documents/MyJava/text.txt")      # also possible
```