# Error reading csv file unicodeescape

Tags: python, csv, unicode-escapes

I have this program

```
import csv

with open("C:\Users\frederic\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.3Qt5\notebooks\scores.txt","r") as scoreFile:
    # write = w, read = r, append = a
    scoreFileReader = csv.reader(scoreFile)
    scoreList = []
    for row in scoreFileReader:
        if len (row) != 0:
            scoreList = scoreList + [row]

scoreFile.close()

print(scoreList)
```

---

**Why do I get this Error ?**

> with
>   open("C:\Users\frederic\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.3Qt5\notebooks\scores.txt","r")
>   as scoreFile:
>                ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python open file unicode error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276283/python-open-file-unicode-error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a SyntaxError for a Unicode escape in my file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084554/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-for-a-unicode-escape-in-my-file-path)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use raw strings with Windows-style filenames:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\frederic\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.3Qt5\notebooks\scores.txt", 'r') as scoreFile:
         ^^
```

Otherwise, Python's string engine thinks that \U is the start of a Unicode escape sequence - which of course it isn't in this case.

---

Also, be careful also your `scoreFile.close()` is useless:

The [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement replace a try and catch. It also
   automatically close the file after the block. That mean you can delete the `scoreFile.close()` line.

Also, you can change the line `if len(row) != 0`
According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty
>   sequences are false.
>
> Yes: if not seq:
>        if seq:
>
> No: if len(seq):
>       if not len(seq):

One last thing, your `for loop` isn't good either, to read `csv` you better start copying an example from the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents) first!

```
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
       print ', '.join(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:

```
import csv
import io

def guess_encoding(csv_file):
    """guess the encoding of the given file"""
    with io.open(csv_file, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read(5)
    if data.startswith(b"\xEF\xBB\xBF"):  # UTF-8 with a "BOM"
        return ["utf-8-sig"]
    elif data.startswith(b"\xFF\xFE") or data.startswith(b"\xFE\xFF"):
        return ["utf-16"]
    else:  # in Windows, guessing utf-8 doesn't work, so we have to try
        try:
            with io.open(csv_file, encoding="utf-8") as f:
                preview = f.read(222222)
                return ["utf-8"]
        except:
            return [locale.getdefaultlocale()[1], "utf-8"]

encodings = guess_encoding(r"C:\Users\frederic\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.3Qt5\notebooks\scores.txt")[0])

# then your code with 
with open(r"C:\Users\frederic\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.3Qt5\notebooks\scores.txt","r", encoding=encodings[0]) as scoreFile:
```