# Loading data from csv file using pandas

Tags: pandas

```
 File "<ipython-input-10-1de27a02fcfe>", line 1
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\niharika\Downloads\questions-data.csv')
                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Even though I place `r` in front of `C`, changing `\` to `/` and also `\\`. Nothing worked to me.could someone please help me.

Comment: Did you try and adding a delimiter to your pd.read_csv argument. It might be that loading engine cannot automatically detect it?

Comment: Could you please elaborate me more,i'm not getting you

Comment: See my answer. cheers

Answer (score 0):

just try 
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\niharika\\Downloads\\questions-data.csv')

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an r in front of the string like this

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\niharika\Downloads\questions-data.csv')
```

This case seems similar to yours

[Error reading csv file unicodeescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895583/error-reading-csv-file-unicodeescape)

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(r'''C:\Users\niharika\Downloads\questions-data.csv''') try fixing the syntax like this