# Process finished with exit code 1 error in python

Tags: python, automation, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I'am trying to automate whatsapp messages in pre-set time. I use pycharm ide.

See the sample code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Replace below path with the absolute path
# to chromedriver in your computer
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/saket/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600)

# Replace 'Friend's Name' with the name of your friend 
# or the name of a group 
target = '"Friend\'s Name"'

# Replace the below string with your own message
string = "Message sent using Python!!!"

x_arg = '//span[contains(@title,' + target + ')]'
group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
    By.XPATH, x_arg)))
group_title.click()
inp_xpath = '//div[@class="input"][@dir="auto"][@data-tab="1"]'
input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
    By.XPATH, inp_xpath)))
for i in range(100):
    input_box.send_keys(string + Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I took this code from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whatsapp-using-python/)

I replaced the chromedriver path in my computer to C:\Users\public\chromedriver.exe but after hit the run button It shows the path is error.

Here's the screenshot.

[chrome driver location error on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYhDm.png)

Can you tell me why that happens though the location is correct?

Comment: Please read [ask] to understand why posting screenshots of code/error messages is bad. Also post the _actual_ code that produced the error - make it as easy for someone to help you as possible. Right now someone willing to help would have to copy your code, edit in your changes, have a look at the screenshot of the error, manually type in the changes again to get to the point where you can reproduce the error.

Comment: Also a quick search of the error here on SO would have given you multiple questions with similar problems, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276283/python-open-file-unicode-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot of the error message (Don't do that! Post text!) shows different source code than the one you have posted.

You have to escape the `\` in your path, so `C:\Users` should be `C:\\Users`.

Comment: Sure Christian I'm new to stack overflow and thanks.