# Downloaded file is damaged in django

Tags: python, django

i am writing this function in views.py file:

```
def download(request):

    file = open("D:\wamp\www\User_App.rar","r")
    mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type("D:\wamp\www\User_App.rar")[0]
    if not mimetype: mimetype = "application/octet-stream"

    response = HttpResponse(file.read(), mimetype=mimetype)
    response["Content-Disposition"]= "attachment; filename=%s" % os.path.split("D:\wamp\www\User_App.rar")[1]
    return response
```

to download file but when that downloads and i open this it is damaged. how to solve this problem.

Comment: A few comments on code style. `file` is a reserved word in python, you shouldn't name your variables `file`. Also: use a context manager to open files, ie `with open(filename) as f: response = HttpResponse(f.read(), mimetype=mimetype)`

Comment: any more suggestions @room2web?

Comment: Don't use one-line if statements :). PEP8 frowns upon them. That said. Read PEP8 :).

Does mimetypes.guess_type(...) always return a non-empty list? If not, you should use `try: ... expect IndexError: ...` to get the mimetype (google Duck Typing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open files in binary mode:

```
file = open(r"D:\wamp\www\User_App.rar", "rb")
```

as opening files in text mode means line endings are translated to a platform-neutral `\n` character.

Comment: what if i want to use `path_to_file = D:\wamp\www\User_App.rar` and then file = open(r"path_to_file", "rb") ,,, but it generates error how to solve this?

Comment: You may want to tell me **what** error it generates.

Comment: @Martijin please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680887/file-reading-error-in-django

Comment: You misunderstood what the `r` does; I used a raw string literal to prevent the ``\`` backslashes in your path from being interpreted as escape sequences.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084554/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-for-a-unicode-escape-in-my-file-path/18084594#18084594 for what options you have