# File reading Error in django

Tags: python, django

Here are the lines to read file & download in django :

```
def download(request):
    file_name =request.GET.get('file_name', '')
    path_to_file = "C:\Users\CV_Uploads\uploadfiles\uploadfiles" + "\\" + file_name

    fileanme = open('r'. path_to_file , "rb")  # **ERROR HERE**
    mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type('path_to_file')[0]
    if not mimetype: mimetype = "application/octet-stream"

    response = HttpResponse(fileanme.read(), mimetype=mimetype)
    response["Content-Disposition"]= "attachment; filename=%s" % os.path.split(path_to_file)[1]
    return response
```

Problem:
Was working fine with hardcoded values but now as i make this code dynamic by joining `path_to_file with file_name` . It says: `AttributeError at /download/ . . . .'str' object has no attribute 'path_to_file'`

How to solve this attribute error?

Comment: print the file_name and path_to_file. and check the different with your hardcoded path.

Comment: just under the `path_to_file = "C:\Users\CV_Uploads\uploadfiles\uploadfiles" + "\\" + file_name` line

Comment: fileanme = open('r'. print path_to_file , "rb") .. like this?

Comment: just write `print path_to_file` and check what it is printed.

Comment: C:\Users\CV_Uploads\uploadfiles\uploadfiles\uploaded_files/1395901478_89_uploadfiles.rar

Comment: This is a follow-up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634610/downloaded-file-is-damaged-in-django; the OP is confused by my use if a raw string literal for the path.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that code is clearly wrong. As the error says, you're taking the string `"r"`, and using the dot notation to call a `path_to_file` attribute on it, which doesn't exist.

I'm not sure what that `r` is supposed to be doing at all. It should work fine without it:

```
fileanme = open(path_to_file , "rb")
```

Comment: it genrates error after downloading file that `the file is either damaged or in unknown format` after removing `r`. @daniel

Comment: I think the OP confused raw string literals; the `r` prefix belongs with the quoting, not the variable.

Comment: hmm so what's the solution @MartijnPieters

Comment: @MartijnPieters Files get damaged after doing this.

Comment: @TameenMalik: then **something else** goes wrong; you are sending the files opened in binary mode, right?

Comment: no .. when i used `fileanme = open(path_to_file , "rb")` compiler generates error that `rb` is undefined

Comment: @TameenMalik no, it does not do that if you use that exact code. Seems like you are having trouble with fairly basic programming concepts: you should probably do an introductory Python tutorial.