# python selenium windows chrome webdriver giving error

Tags: windows, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the following errors while trying all the solutions I could find on my own with no success like copying the whole selenium folder to main python folder, changing the path, using the absolute path etc, I would really appreciate the help as a newbie who just got started with python and selenium.

```
C:\Users\WorkStation\Desktop\chromedriver.exe
```

> Error : -
>
> C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
>   C:/Users/WorkStation/PycharmProjects/test/scraptest/scrap.py   File
>   "C:/Users/WorkStation/PycharmProjects/test/scraptest/scrap.py", line 3
>       driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\WorkStation\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
>                                ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated
>   \UXXXXXXXX escape
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Then I tried this and now more errors:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\WorkStation\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe")
```

> Error : -
>
> C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
>   C:/Users/WorkStation/PycharmProjects/test/scraptest/scrap.py Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 74, in start
>       stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)   File "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 665, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)   File
>   "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 910, in _get_handles
>       c2pwrite = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(self._get_devnull())   File "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 770, in _get_devnull
>       self._devnull = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nul'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/WorkStation/PycharmProjects/test/scraptest/scrap.py", line
>   3, in 
>       driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\WorkStation\Desktop\chromedriver.exe") 
>   File
>   "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
>   line 62, in **init**
>       self.service.start()   File "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 81, in start
>       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
>   'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
>
> Exception ignored in: >
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 173, in **del**
>       self.stop()   File "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 145, in stop
>       if self.process is None: AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Even after copying the selenium files from the site-packages folder to the main python folder and adding the absolute path is not working
After doing the above step here is the error

> C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
>   C:/Users/WorkStation/PycharmProjects/test/scraptest/scrap.py Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 74, in start
>       stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)   File "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 665, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)   File
>   "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 910, in _get_handles
>       c2pwrite = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(self._get_devnull())   File "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 770, in _get_devnull
>       self._devnull = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nul'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/WorkStation/PycharmProjects/test/scraptest/scrap.py", line
>   3, in 
>       driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe")
>   File
>   "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
>   line 62, in **init**
>       self.service.start()   File "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 81, in start
>       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
>   'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
>
> Exception ignored in: >
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 173, in **del**
>       self.stop()   File "C:\Users\WorkStation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 145, in stop
>       if self.process is None: AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Here is the screenshot of the issue in PyCharm

[image]

System Config:

```
windows  32-bit 
PyDispatcher    2.0.5   2.0.5
attrs   16.3.0  16.3.0
beautifulsoup4  4.5.3   4.5.3
cffi    1.9.1   1.9.1
constantly  15.1.0  15.1.0
cryptography    1.7.1   1.7.1
cssselect   1.0.0   1.0.0
idna    2.2 2.2
incremental 16.10.1 16.10.1
mechanize   0.2.5   0.2.5
pip 9.0.1   9.0.1
pyOpenSSL   16.2.0  16.2.0
pyasn1  0.1.9   0.1.9
pyasn1-modules  0.0.8   0.0.8
pycparser   2.17    2.17
requests    2.12.4  2.12.4
selenium    3.0.2   3.0.2
service-identity    16.0.0  
setuptools  32.3.1  32.3.1
six 1.10.0  1.10.0
urllib3 1.19.1  1.19.1
wheel   0.29.0  0.30.0a0
zope.interface  4.3.3   4.3.3
Chrome webdriver Latest Version 2.27
Chrome browser Version Version 55.0.2883.87 m (Up to date)
```

Comment: Check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42478941/5986816

Answer (score 3):

[This SO Q&A might answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084554/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-for-a-unicode-escape-in-my-file-path)

I had this problem and I changed the `backslash (\\)` to `forward slash (/)`.

try this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/WorkStation/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: Sure will try this out