# Python Selenium Chrome Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm beginning the automate the boring stuff book and I'm trying to open a chrome web browser through python. I have already installed selenium and

I have tried to run this file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://automatetheboringstuff.com')
```

But because of that I get this Error:

> 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
 line 74, in start
     stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
     restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
     startupinfo) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Program Files
(x86)/Python36-32/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
line 62, in __init__
   self.service.start()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
line 81, in start
   os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver'
  executable needs to be in PATH. Please see
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: The traceback already tells you, what the problem is: your python code can not execute `chromedriver` as it can not be found in PATH. Add the location of `chromedriver`to PATH or move `chromedriver` to a place already in PATH.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium - chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555930/selenium-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You need to **specify the path where your chromedriver is located**.

1. [Download chromedriver for your desired platform from here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/?pli=1).
2. Place chromedriver on your system path, or where your code is.
3. If not using a system path, link your `chromedriver.exe` (For non-Windows users, it's just called `chromedriver`):

   ```
   browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
   ```

   (Set `executable_path` to the location where your chromedriver is located.)

   If you've placed chromedriver on your System Path, you can shortcut by just doing the following:

   `browser = webdriver.Chrome()`
4. If you're running on a Unix-based operating system, you may need to update the permissions of chromedriver after downloading it in order to make it executable:

   `chmod +x chromedriver`
5. That's all. If you're still experiencing issues, more info can be found on this other StackOverflow article: [Can't use chrome driver for Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130109/cant-use-chrome-driver-for-selenium)

Comment: or just do what the error message stated and put the executable somewhere in your system PATH

Comment: alternative: [Selenium-Driverless](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Driverless) in python

Answer (score 46):

Here's a simpler solution: install python-chromedrive package, import it in your script, and it's done.

**Step by step**:
1. pip install chromedriver-binary
2. import the package

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary  # Adds chromedriver binary to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-binary/

Comment: You need to perform pip install chromedriver-binary

Comment: @Prometheus Yes I mentioned that in step 1

Comment: This wasn't working for me because pip install chromedriver_binary installs the latest version (84), but my chrome version is 83. So I had to run pip install  chromedriver-binary==83.0.4103.39. You can find other versions here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Comment: It's very simple, it doesn't  work

Comment: This no longer works.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/1896134

Comment: pip install chromedriver-binary-auto