# Getting this selenium error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: '' executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python, selenium, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Installed Selenium on my IntellIJ. I am trying to complete exercise 2.1
at http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html .

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python27\Scripts/")
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Which produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "B:\Program Files (x86)\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "B:\Program Files (x86)\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:/Alexander/Documents/PythonPrograms/Selenium/Test.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python27\Scripts/")
  File "B:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "B:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 86, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
**selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: '' executable may have wrong permissions**. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: I do not see any question here.

Comment: I am getting "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: '' executable may have wrong permissions" and I dont know how about to fix it.

Comment: (OT) "B:\Program Files (x86)" ?! I sense someone who was born too late to see the floppy disk era...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium Chrome Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478591/python-selenium-chrome-webdriver)

Comment: No intent to be condescending. Just was amused by a "total lack of respect for letters A: and B:" ) The fact that ppl born after 2000 are now getting old enough to program is just a fact of life - regardless of whether you're one or not.

Answer (score 0):

[The code that triggers the exception](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py#L86) looks like this:

```
def start(self):
<...>
    try:
        cmd = [self.path]
        cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, <...>)
<...>
    except OSError as err:
<...>
        elif err.errno == errno.EACCES:
            raise WebDriverException(
                "'%s' executable may have wrong permissions. %s" % (
                    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
```

As you can see, `''` in the error message means that `os.path.basename(self.path)` is empty. And the message being formulated like this suggests that the code's author didn't intend it to be empty.

Let's see what it's initialized from. [Searching the repo for references](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=self.path%20%3D&type=) brings us to [`py/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py:37`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/9f6aaa6f97dd786d407b5947a8082dbc2624805a/py/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py#L35):

```
class Service:

    def __init__(self, executable, port=0, log_file=DEVNULL, env=None, start_error_message=""):
        self.path = executable
    <...>
```

Which means, `self.path` is **the first argument you passed to `webdriver.Chrome`**, i.e. `"C:\Python27\Scripts/"`. Since it's then passed to `subprocess` as the program to execute, **it should be a path to an executable file**, not to a directory. Judging by other results in the search above, **the path to Chrome executable**. In the example, a Firefox driver is started without arguments, but as the search results show, it seems to have autodetection from profile or something.