# webdriver.Chrome() is not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, chrome-web-driver

I am trying to use Selenium with Python 3. I installed Selenium and Chrome Webdriver. Pip was pre-installed with Python 3. However, i am getting this error message. I literally started learning this language yesterday, so please be kind if the error is silly.

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.close()
```

**Error message**

```
"C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe" 
"C:/Users/.../.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/Hello World.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/.../.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/Hello World.py", line 4, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Somehow I still can't relate the error at `Hello World.py", line 4` with the line of code `driver.close()` in your script. Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : no module named selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium)

Comment: It looks like the selenium package is not installed correctly.

Comment: It does not work when I try to run it by PyCharm. It seems to work otherwise. How do I fix this?

Comment: @VrajShroff i ran your code and it didn't run. After i included **chrome driver executable path** and it ran properly. Did you try my following answer. I'm pretty sure it will solve your problem. However, without PyCharm , did you try to run your code on another IDE ?

Comment: @VrajShroff and recheck if selenium is installed properly or install it - `pip install selenium` command. Please, let's inform your action on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium Chrome Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478591/python-selenium-chrome-webdriver)

Comment: @VrajShroff please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42478941/9215780). You'll get the answer and please let me know.

Comment: @VrajShroff I would guess that your Pycharm project is using a different virtual environment than when you are running outside pycharm.

You have to install selenium in the virtualenv set in your pycharm project:

`C:\Users\Vraj Shroff\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\pip.exe install selenium`

Comment: @iPhoton unfortunately your answer did not fix it. I am not entirely sure what jbch means but the following (my answer) fixed the issue. It might be what you are hinting at.

Comment: @VrajShroff in which IDE you're running your code ? PyCharm ? Did you try to run your code in sublime or jupyter notebook ?

Comment: Yes, I was trying PyCharm. Unfortunately, I do not have access to any other IDE. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to download the stable release of Chromedriver, Then it will work

go to this link and download it - https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Answer (score -2):

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    url = 'https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en'
    driver.get(url)
```

It should work. It worked for me :)

Comment: This will result in a NameError, as the variable `driver` is undefined.