# Why is my webdriver.chrome() not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-options

Before I get blasted in my comments on this question, I am well aware that this is a possible duplication of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336283/webdriver-chrome-is-not-working), but the answer provided is not helping me out with my instance of code, even after applying an adjusted version of the answer in my code. I have looked into many answers, including installing Chromedriver into my device, but to no avail.

My code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\chromedriver_win32')
driver.get('http://codepad.org')

text_area = driver.find_element_by_id('textarea')
text_area.send_keys("This text is send using Python code.")
```

Every time I run the code, including the `executable_path = r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\chromedriver_win32'`
I keep getting a permission error message when I run the code with the executable path.
My code without the path is the same minus the `executable_path` which I replace with `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options)`, but I get the error message `argument of type 'Options' is not iterable`.

Any help with this problem is greatly appreciated. Admittedly I am a bit new to Python, and coding, in general, and I am trying new ideas to learn the program better, but everything that I try to find an answer to just breaks my code in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the executable file name at the end of executable_path argument:

```
executable_path = r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
```

Code I used for testing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://codepad.org')

text_area = driver.find_element_by_id('textarea')
text_area.send_keys("This text is send using Python code.")
```

Comment: When I ran the code after adding the execuable_path argument to the options variable, I got a TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'. And the Executable Path argument was added to the driver variable as shown in my code above.

Comment: @MichaelPate I added the code I used for testing to my answer. It works fine on my end. Did you make any changes to it?

Comment: I get a permission error message. It might just be my device, which is really annoying but I have a working code that just needs the proper permissions. So if the code works on your end, its just a problem with my device.