# python-selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unknown error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm up with python 3.8 and selenium but recently I downloaded the latest edge web driver zip file and runned the mswdedriver.exe from that and typed this code in my ide:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Edge('‪F:\za\python\Assistant\msedgedriver.exe')
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url='http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

but I see this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'MicrosoftEdgeDriver' executable needs to be 
in PATH. Please download from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687
```

Can you help me friends?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give a path to the webdriver executable when you load a webdriver, or have it stored as an environment variable:

```py
webdriver.Edge(executable_path="path/to/executable")
```

A web driver is essentially a special browser application, you must install that application before you can run anything with it.

Here's Edge's web driver [download page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/). Or you can use the link from the error message http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687

Here's a similar question [Python Selenium Chrome Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478591/python-selenium-chrome-webdriver)

Comment: If you do not know how to add it to your environment variable it has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho/44272417 If you complete these steps your code will work as is, but if you want add the executable file as the answer states into the `webdriver.Edge`.

Comment: but giving the path as `F:\za\python\Assistant\msedgedriver.exe` I still see the folowing error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'msedgedriver.exe' executable needs to be 
in PATH. Please download from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687`

Comment: Could you edit your original post to reflect your code change?

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes in the executable path need to be escaped, per Python syntax:

```
browser = webdriver.Edge('‪F:\\za\\python\\Assistant\\msedgedriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears to me
you must put in "**Bin Folder**" the file "**MicrosoftWebDriver.exe**" as is , edit the previous name of edge webdriver to be "MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" and put it in the "Bin Folder"

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to download the browser driver from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)
2. After the download completes, extract the driver executable to your preferred location. Add the folder where the executable is located to your PATH environment variable.