# How to get past Javascript is disabled in your browser error when web scraping with Python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to create a script to download an ebook into a pdf. When I try to use beautifulsoup in it I to print the contents of a single page, I get a message in the console stating "Oh no! It looks like JavaScript is disabled in your browser. Please re-enable to access the reader."
I have already enabled Javascript in Chrome and this same piece of code works for a page like a stackO answer page. What could be blocking Javascript in this page and how can I bypass it?

My code for reference:

```
url = requests.get("https://platform.virdocs.com/r/s/0/doc/350551/sp/14552484/mi/47443495/?cfi=%2F4%2F2%5BP7001013978000000000000000003FF2%5D%2F2%2F2%5BP7001013978000000000000000010019%5D%2F2%2C%2F1%3A0%2C%2F1%3A0")
url.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")
elems = soup.select("p")

print(elems[0].getText())
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the page actually contains no content. To load the content it needs to run some JS code. The `requests.get` method does not run JS, it just loads the basic HTML.

What you need to do is to emulate a browser, i.e. 'open' the page, run JS, and then scrape content. One way to do it is to use a browser driver as described here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57912823/9805867