# Python urllib.request - How to setup headers

Tags: python, html, header, urllib

I need to set up headers for `urllib.request` to get the real page and avoid redirection. If I use just this code:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://open.spotify.com/artist/4npEfmQ6YuiwW1GpUmaq3F", "test.html")
```

Spotify recognizes that I use an unsupported browser and will redirect me to a different page. I need to get the original HTML and I think the setup headers can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set headers using python's urllib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933417/how-do-i-set-headers-using-pythons-urllib)

Comment: If you're trying to emulate the browser, you may be better off using Selenium instead of urllib https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933417/how-do-i-set-headers-using-pythons-urllib) post. Also follows on from your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65392491/python-curl-output-different-from-original-html) about `curl`.

Comment: I know the selenium is better fo it but I cant use it because I need this process on the background and also multiplatform.

Comment: @costaparas Thanks for the advice but I am still not sure which contract should by inside header.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Have you tried adding both headers mentioned in the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65392491/python-curl-output-different-from-original-html)? Did it not work?

Comment: I ran your code (as is) and it works. Are you running it locally? When you open test.htm in notepad does it contain the HTML you expect?

Comment: I try this: from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://open.spotify.com/artist/711MCceyCBcFnzjGY4Q7Un')
req.add_header('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.2 Safari/605.1.15')
content = urlopen(req).read()

print(content)

Comment: But it still returns the redirected page

Comment: @Greg Yes is possible to run the code but if you open the URL in the web browser you will get the right page but if you run the code it will store another (some redirected page)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if a `request` adds a `user-agent`, Spotify will preform additional checks. This may be fixed by adding all the headers. Alternatively you can set the user agent to a Brower that Spotify doesn't know about e.g *TEST*.

I've got the following scrape code to work without any headers, so I wouldn't admit headers unless there was a specific reason. (I've only added it, because of the question in the title).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/711MCceyCBcFnzjGY4Q7Un',
 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4npEfmQ6YuiwW1GpUmaq3F'
]
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'TEST'
}

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    html = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    #print(soup.prettify())
    print(soup.find('h1').text.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
AC/DC
Ava Max
```