# How to check if a chrome webpage is loaded using python (WebBrowser)?

Tags: python, google-chrome, webautomation

This is my code right here in Python and I am using web browser module and pyautogui module.

I wanted a way in which I can check if the webpage is loaded completely so that the required actions do not take place at a blank screen.

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui, time

url = 'youtube.com'  # or something else


chrome_path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

webbrowser.register("chrome", None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))

webbrowser.get("chrome").open_new_tab(url)
```

I want to execute the below code after the page is completely loaded. Currently i am using the `time.sleep` manual function but it doesn't work pretty well and is inefficient

```
time.sleep(20)

pyautogui.leftClick(484, 447)
```

Comment: shouldn't you be using selenium for this? selenium can wait for the precise element on the screen to be loaded / become visible

Comment: Yes, I should use selenium but the problem with selenium is that is always opens the webpage in internet explorer so I had to use web browser.

Comment: you can use other browsers too in selenium... i use chrome myself 

Comment: Umm.. Can you pls help me out. Whatever I try it always opens in Internet Explorer. Any Fix??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478591/python-selenium-chrome-webdriver