# Whenever I try to call driver window with the help of driver.get() function it throws error in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Whenever I type the following code, it throws an error and I am not able to connect to my driver window:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
```

> Error message: InvalidArgumentException

Comment: at which location do you have `chromedriver.exe`? Also, I believe you already have this import `from selenium import webdriver`

Comment: yes done all that, location also is correct

Answer (score 0):

1. Download chromedriver.exe
2. Set executable_path to the location where your chromedriver is located.
3. replace **driver = webdriver.Chrome("**chromedriver.exe**")** to
   **driver = webdriver.Chrome()**
4. Chekc It will work or not.

for more info check below link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42478941/6559285