# Trying to open a webpage using selenium but getting error

Tags: python, selenium, python-webbrowser

I wrote this simple code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
webdriver.Chrome().get('www.google.co.in')
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\WebAutomation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\WebAutomation\venv\Automation.py", line 2, in <module>
    webdriver.Chrome().get('www.google.co.in')
 File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\WebAutomation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\WebAutomation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\WebAutomation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

Someone please help me. I'm a beginner, please explain/guide in detail (I don't know complex concepts)

Comment: your code will launch 'Chrome.exe' [install method for chrome driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42478941/3996078)

Comment: Can you please provide the full solution, as it will be easier to spot any issues

Answer (score 0):

You will need additional the Selenium-Chrome-Driver.exe!
The last line of errors tells this to you.

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

The driver itself will be started from your programm and will hold the binding between your program and the browser chrome itself.

The driver.exe can be easily placed in the programm-startup-path (I recommend this for the first steps) or placed where ever you want, but than you must define the special variable of the PATH to the driver.exe.

You can get the driver.exe behind this link:

Main page:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Download Page:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Please ensure, that your Browser-Version match to the driver-Version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).