# How to use selenium chrome options?

Tags: python, selenium

So I have had this code for sometime that worked without an issue for what I can recall. However, it has recently been raising an issue when I run it. Here is the code

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

here is the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install ChromeDriver if it's not installed. (https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Then, you need to add it to the PATH environment variable and you're good to go!

Comment: I understand but that is something I am not trying to do. I want to be able to use this code without having to install and add a chromedriver to PATH. Like I said previously this code used to work but now it doesn't, was there a change in the package?

Comment: I don't think that you can use it without installing chromedriver. But if you don't want to add it to the PATH then you can specify path for webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/your/path/to/chromedriver"), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42478941/14226346.