# Address error: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode

Tags: python, image

Code to show image is giving a syntax error when I use the Address to the image.

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

Scare = Tk()
Scare.title('?????')
Countdown = 2
CountTotal = 2
CountTotal = IntVar()

def CountdownWork():
    global Countdown
    if Countdown > 0:
        Countdown = Countdown -1
        CountTotal.set(Countdown)
        Scare.after(1000, CountdownWork)
    else:
        ImageAddress = 'C:\Users\KINSLED\Desktop\New folder\ScareTest.jpg'
        ImageItself = Image.open(ImageAddress)
        ImageNumpyFormat = np.asarray(ImageItself)
        plt.imshow(ImageNumpyFormat)
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(5) # pause how many seconds
        plt.close()



Count = Label(Scare, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), textvariable=CountTotal, 
bd=30, bg='SeaGreen1', justify='right').grid(row=7,columnspan=8)

CountdownWork()

Scare.mainloop()
```

The Syntax Error is highlighting the space just after the equals in ImageAdress.

The Error is:

> (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated\UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a SyntaxError for a Unicode escape in my file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084554/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-for-a-unicode-escape-in-my-file-path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Python strings, the backslash `"\"` is a special character, also called the "escape" character. It is used in representing certain whitespace characters: `"\t"` is a tab, `"\n"` is a newline, and `"\r"` is a carriage return.

I believe the error is referencing your adress, specifically the special character `"\"` in it. You cannot use `"\"` in your string as it will escape the string. You could try using `"\\"` in your address, I think this should work.

Please see here for futher reading on the subject: http://www.pitt.edu/~naraehan/python2/tutorial7.html

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that the slash would interfere. It works now.

Comment: OK, but this also occurs in comments,  e.g. `''' C:\Users '''`. Yet, it doesn't occur with comments starting with '#', e.g.  `# C:\Users'. This looks insane, since comments starting with ''' should be just ignored, like those starting with '#'!

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in the way you've typed the file path. Windows uses backslashes `\` to separate files and directories in filenames, but any time the interpreter sees these special characters, it looks for an unicode escape sequnce, like `\n`. To insert a backslash you need to insert `\\`, one slash to trigger the escape sequence and another to indicate the backslash itlesf as the desired special character.

Your assignment then becomes

```
ImageAddress = 'C\\:Users\\KINSLED\\Desktop\\New folder\\ScareTest.jpg'
```

which does't throw any error on my simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `\` use `/` in python. This way you can overcome this

```
(Unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated\UXXXXXXXX escape" error
```