# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode

Tags: python, list, append

I want to take the text of a file, each new value on a new line, for example `hi /n this is my question /n can u answer it?`

My_list should look like this `My_list[0]` should be equal to `hi`, `My_list[1]` should be equal to `this is my question` and `My_list[2]` should be equal to `can u answer it?`

I tried doing so using the following

```
with open(r'path.docx',encoding="utf8") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

in an approach like the one i found in here [How do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-I-list)
Then i got a `Syntax error for unicode` do i referred to this link [Why do I get a SyntaxError for a Unicode escape in my file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084554/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-for-a-unicode-escape-in-my-file-path) added `r` at first and solved it for the first iteration then got this error

```
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>
```

that i referred to this link to solve [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character) and added `encoding="utf8"`. Still not working .

**EDIT:** I changed the encoding to `"Latin-1"` but i didn't get the output i want from `print (content)` instead i got stuff like that `['PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00\t$\x87\` , again what i want and expect is a list where each line of the .docx file is an element(seperated by /n).

Comment: Adding `encoding="utf-8"` only works if your file is actually utf-8 encoded, obviously.

Comment: What is the actual error message when you tried with UTF8? What is the encoding of the file `path.docx`? Is it UTF8 as you assume? You could check with unix `file path.docx` command, or by using the [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) Python package.

Comment: I tried "Latin-1" instead of "utf-8" I didn't get an error but print content basically printed nonsense, I'll update my question to showcase.

Comment: That is not a text file but a binary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file is a docx file, which is a pkzip compressed archive.

You can't open it as though it is a text file.

Instead you could look at an external package such as [python-docx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-docx). Something like this might work for you:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document('path.docx')
content = [p.text for p in doc.paragraphs]
```

Comment: I used 'pip install docx' then ran the code according to your adjustments and got the following error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'' where this line 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'' exists in 'docx.py'

Comment: @Jimmy: you should `pip install python-docx`. Uninstall `docx` first just to make sure that there are no clashes.

Answer (score 0):

From the last link you give, I think the problem is that the file you are trying to read is not UTF-8 encoded.  Have you tried with another encoding? There is a list [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Comment: May you supply a method to know exactly what encoding the file is so I can check.