# SyntaxError (unicode error) when trying to read Matlab file in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a Matlab file in Python, but it gives an error. Can anyone help me out?

I run the following code:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
data = loadmat('C:\Users\Sakraan\Desktop\stomachpain.mat')
```

but I get the following error:

```
data = loadmat('C:\Users\Sakraan\Desktop\stomachpain.mat')
                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in
position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: please do not post pictures of errors. Edit the post and post the error and the code causing it. See [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a SyntaxError for a Unicode escape in my file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084554/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-for-a-unicode-escape-in-my-file-path)

Answer (score 1):

The `\U` from your path relating to `C:\Users...` is an Unicode escape. In order to get your path to work you would have to duplicate all of the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to duplicate all of the backslashes