# change directory in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from PIL import Image
import os

for f in os.listdir('C:\Users\diodi\Pictures'):
    if f.endswith('.jpg'):
        print(f)
```

i get the error

for f in os.listdir('C:\Users\diodi\Pictures'):
                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

if someone can edit the error message please do.

i want to print the names of the pictures(jpg) i have in 
 ('C:\Users\diodi\Pictures')

i am using python 3.7,i know i didn't use the pillow library yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a SyntaxError for a Unicode escape in my file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084554/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-for-a-unicode-escape-in-my-file-path)

Answer (score 2):

The backslashes are being parsed as escape characters, use r to denote raw string

```
os.listdir(r"C:\Users\diodi\Pictures"):
```

Or escape them with more backslashes

```
os.listdir('C:\\Users\\diodi\\Pictures'):
```

Comment: I'd say watch some YouTube tutorials, and have a look over the handbook: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/handbook/index.html