# Jupyter Notebook not uploading CSV file, despite trying various solutions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, plotly

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3AdJ.png) I am trying to upload a CSV file on Jupyter Notebooks, and I have tried using the solutions on this post:

[Why do I get a SyntaxError for a Unicode escape in my file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084554/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-for-a-unicode-escape-in-my-file-path)

There were a few other articles which suggested the same things.

When I tried the first suggestion I got this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-11b40256508f> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Naveed\Desktop\RateStats.csv')
      2 df.head()

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    700                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    701 
--> 702         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    703 
    704     parser_f.__name__ = name

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    427 
    428     # Create the parser.
--> 429     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    430 
    431     if chunksize or iterator:

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1120     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1121         if engine == 'c':
-> 1122             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1123         else:
   1124             if engine == 'python':

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1851         kwds['usecols'] = self.usecols
   1852 
-> 1853         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1854         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1855 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:\\Users\\Naveed\\Desktop\\RateStats.csv' does not exist: b'C:\\Users\\Naveed\\Desktop\\RateStats.csv'
```

However, it was still not working. I'm not sure if the fact that I am using Jupyter thru labs.cognitiveclass.ai has anything to do with it, but I didn't think it to be the issue. I tried it on the Jupyter installed on my computer, and still was not able to upload the CSV.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

I expected to at least be able to output the first few rows of data, instead of the error message.

Comment: You can search for directories and files interactively in a notebook.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Naveed\\Desktop\\RateStats.csv')
```

or

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Naveed/Desktop/RateStats.csv')
```

the problem was because when you tried to do use

```
'C:\Users
```

The `\U` is a unicode escape character.

Also if it's a file not found error, you need to make sure that the `RateStats` file is present in the given path.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the output

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Naveed\\Desktop\\RateStats.csv').head()