# Issue with Path Directories in Python

Tags: python, import, syntax, directory

I'm working on loading a directory containing a bunch of images that I'm going to process. I am using the Azure Notebooks, and I copied the directory correctly by right-clicking + choosing 'Properties', so I don't think that it's an issue to do with how I selected my path. This is what I have tried so far:

```
import os
data_dir = 'C:\Users\User Name\Downloads\cell_image'
```

This is a direct copy of the path, but it returns the following Syntax Error: *(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape*

I then tried converting the string by putting r in front of it (and by manually adding escape \ characters to the backslashes in the string), and both returned the error shown below.

```
import os
data_dir = r'C:\Users\User Name\Downloads\cell_image'
os.listdir(data_dir)
```

This returns the following error: *No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\User Name\Downloads\cell_image'*

Any thoughts on how to resolve this? It's preventing me from loading my data, so any help that you can give would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: If you copied your path from a Windows properties window, it might contain invisible characters that mess up the path. Put `print(repr(data_dir))` in your program and see if there's anything weird.

Comment: I just tried that — I got the path as 'C:\\Users\\User Name\\Downloads\\cell_image'.

Comment: It doesn't exactly seem weird on first glance, it's just got escape characters. Any thoughts on what might be going wrong?

Comment: If it's not that, then the path must just be wrong. You could try each part in turn to find the problem, so try `'C:/Users'` then `'C:/Users/User Name'` etc. until you find the part that doesn't work. (I presume you replace `User Name` with your actual username.)

Comment: By the way, it's easier to use forward slashes than backslashes.

Comment: @khelwood, it says there's no such file or directory even when I just use C:/Users, so I think something is going weird earlier in the process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a SyntaxError for a Unicode escape in my file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084554/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-for-a-unicode-escape-in-my-file-path)

Comment: @TheVishal that was the one I started off with. I tried all of those solutions before making the post, and none of them have seemed to solve it.

Comment: Try opening windows explorer and pasting"C:\Users\User Name\Downloads\cell_image" into it. Does it open a directory? What about command prompt: `cd C:\Users\User Name\Downloads\cell_image`?

Comment: What do you get from `print(os.path.expanduser('~'))`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have you replaced user name with the name of your account. (Sorry, this may sound very stupid to some but I just wanted to check.)

Next look at khelwoods comment. I would suggest you typing out the path instead of copying and pasting.

Then try changing it into variable = os.listdir("path")
This will list the content of the directory and assign that string to your variable.

Otherwise I would try this in the python shell and doing it without assigning it to a variable, instead justing printing it.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah — the User Name part is just a stand-in for my actual username, because I'm on a work computer. I'm really not quite sure why it can't see my directory.

Answer (score 0):

"/" is the python escape character, youd need to use "//"

Comment: Typo "/" != "\" ?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the slash/backslash character (see comment).