# Why can't copy the directory into site-packages?

Tags: python-3.x

Dual os in my pc, window10 + debian,the module `analyse` works fine in my debian,i copy it into `c:\mydoc\analyse`,reboot into win10.

```
import shutil
shutil.copy('c:\mydoc\analyse','C:\Users\pengsir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages')
```

It encounter a problem:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

How to copy the directory into my window10's python library?

```
>>> import  shutil
>>> shutil.copy(r'c:\mydoc\analyse',r'C:\Users\pengsir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pengsir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 248, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\pengsir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\mydoc\\analyse'
```

I have run `cmd` with `admin` permission.

Comment: Try to use raw-strings in your path: 
`shutil.copy(r'c:\mydoc\analyse',r'C:\Users\pengsir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a SyntaxError for a Unicode escape in my file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084554/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-for-a-unicode-escape-in-my-file-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Escape with  `\\` --double `\`.
2. Use `copytree` method to copy directory to destination.

   ```
   shutil.copytree('c:\\mydoc\\analyse','C:\\Users\\pengsir\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\analyse')
   ```