# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codes can't decode bytes in position 12-13 truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python, anaconda, syntax-error, jupyter, unicode-escapes

I tried using `pd.read_csv("C:\Users\mfk15\Desktop\DM\tweets.xlsx")` but there is still an error. I use windows anaconda Jupyter notebook.

this is the error I faces now

```
File "<ipython-input-4-200f7da6a93c>", line 1
data_imdb = pd.read_csv("‪C:\Users\mfk15\Desktop\DM\tweets.xlsx", delimiter='\t', header=None)
                        ^
```

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 12-13: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escap

Additional traceback for `OSError`:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-c18122f86667> in <module>
----> 1 data_imdb=pandas.read_csv("‪C:/Users/mfk15/anaconda3/tweets.csv", delimiter='\t', header=None)
      2 data_imdb.columns = ["tweetText", "tweetCreated","Location"]
      3 
      4 data_imdb

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     )
    685 
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    687 
    688 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    450 
    451     # Create the parser.
--> 452     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    453 
    454     if chunksize or iterator:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    944             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    945 
--> 946         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    947 
    948     def close(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1176     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1177         if engine == "c":
-> 1178             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1179         else:
   1180             if engine == "python":

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   2006         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   2007 
-> 2008         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   2009         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   2010 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aC:/Users/mfk15/anaconda3/tweets.csv'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a SyntaxError for a Unicode escape in my file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084554/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-for-a-unicode-escape-in-my-file-path)

Answer (score 2):

you are reading an excel file with a wrong pandas element, replace read_csv, with read_excel and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all the backslash with forward slash

```py
pd.read_csv("‪C:/Users/mfk15/Desktop/DM/tweets.xlsx", delimiter='\t', header=None)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\mfk15\Desktop\DM\tweets.xlsx")
```