# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 7-8: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
os.system("cd C:\Users\Adarshkrdubay\AppData\Local\Programs\BurpSuiteCommunity")
```

File "c:\adarshkrdubay\Exp\Exp-1.py", line 99
os.system("cd r'C:\Users\Adarshkrdubay\AppData\Local\Programs\BurpSuiteCommunity'")
^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 7-8: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a SyntaxError for a Unicode escape in my file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084554/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-for-a-unicode-escape-in-my-file-path)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a raw string.

Raw strings: `r"cd C:\Users\rest\of\path"`